# how to filter product list using custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.7

I created one attribute brand with values 'only' and 'unbranded'. Now I want to  filter product list by brand names for customer. I tried following code

In local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Newlist.php

```
 class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Newlist extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
 {
   protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
      $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();

         $collection->addAttributeToSelect('brand')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('brand', array('eq' => 'only'))
         ;

      return $collection;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this using following code

```
      $_productCollection->clear()
        ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                array('attribute'=> 'brand','eq' => 'Only'),
                array('attribute'=> 'brand','eq' => 'VeroModa'),
            )

        ->load();
```